# Unbind the client click event of a asp button but keep the server click event of the asp button attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, controls

I need to fire the server click event inside the client click event for some specific condition. I know, if client click returns true then server click event is fired.
OnClientClick I am showing a jConfirm. I want to fire the server click of the same button when jConfirm returns true. I am trying this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ValidationGroup="Add" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate()" />


function Validate() {
     if (Page_ClientValidate('Add')) {
         if ($('#<%=ddlTestField.ClientID%>').val() == '0') {
             var strMessage = 'Continue?';
             $.alerts.okButton = 'OK';
             $.alerts.cancelButton = 'CANCEL';
             jConfirm(strMessage, 'CONFIRM MESSAGE', function (r) {
                if(r)
                {
                    $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').unbind("click"); // To unbind the client event
                    $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(); // To fire the server click event, But it is firing the client click also. A loop goes on
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As you're using `asp.net` events, I suggest you do this with two buttons - the `runat=server` one hidden and a client-only one that calls your `btnAdd_Click` and then calls $("Button1").click()`

Comment: @freedomn-m Currently I am managing with exactly the way you said. But, is this the only way, adding an additional html button & keeping the asp button hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
if(r)
{
      <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, String.Empty) %>;
}
```